# how to embed one html page in extjs4

Tags: extjs, extjs4

I started with extjs 4, my current problem: insert a html code. here i need to insert that code into the 'items'. So my lack of experience should not be done. Looking forward to receiving help from people

**"here is the code"**

```
 Ext.define('MyDesktop.mytree', {
        extend: 'Ext.ux.desktop.Module',
        requires: [
           'Ext.tree.Panel',
           'Ext.data.TreeStore',
            'Ext.form.field.HtmlEditor',

        ],

        id:'tree',

        init : function(){
            this.launcher = {         
                //title
                text: 'My Computer',
                //icon
                iconCls:'notepad'

            };
        },


        createWindow : function(){

            var desktop = this.app.getDesktop();
            var win = desktop.getWindow('tree');        
            if(!win){
                win = desktop.createWindow({
                    id: 'tree',
                    title:'MyComputer',

                    width:600,
                    height:400,
                    iconCls: 'notepad',
                    animCollapse:false,
                    border: false,
                    hideMode: 'offsets',
                    columns:3,


                      items: [
                            {


                            },



                        ]         
                });

            }

            return win;
        }   

    });
```

Answer (score 1):

There are three way that you can apply HTML code in ExtJS
  1. html config
  2. autoEl config
  3. XTemplate class

Please refer below link for your guidelines and example.

http://www.marcusschiesser.de/2009/01/3-ways-to-render-html-inside-of-a-extjs-container/

Thanks.

Comment: I am very happy to receive help from you, thank you very much.
Wish you a happy day

Comment: Can you help me then no problem: I want to insert the code given in 1 html page, not all pages. Is there any way?